# how to save a output in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

i have a mongodb that it has many column Contains Id , name and phone number.I used a command to get the length of the phone numbers.I want to add the output obtained from the length of the phone numbers in a column to my database.I used the following command for this

```html
db.rs1.aggregate( [ { $project: { "_id": 1,"phone number": 1, "length": { $strLenCP: "$phone number" }; ])
```

But the output (length) just appears, but not saved.How can I add this output(length) as a new column to my database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aggregation with update in mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384871/aggregation-with-update-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

It's a duplicate question weather you intended or not :)

The aggregation pipeline and the update is done in two different steps.

better look here [Aggregation with update in mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384871/aggregation-with-update-in-mongodb)

Comment: I did not notice anything from the link you sent me to. In that link, it uses <<cust_to_clear = db.col.aggregate>> if in my database this line is not readable.

Comment: you should replace it with your table name .

Comment: i means this part << cust_to_clear >> . i change the name of << cust_to_clear >> But it makes a mistake.

Comment: The answers are meant to be run as a script inside mongo terminal .
this will surly help you:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/

Comment: i have a problem in script. i have a error in mongodb shell .when i used <<a= db.name collection.aggregate>> in shell i have a error. how to use a script in mongodb shell?